# C++/cli/clr вопрос архитектуры приложения и компонентов

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

вопрос архитектуры, где правильно объявить класс с учётом что он используется в аппликации (C#) и двух сателитных длл(C++clr)? Чтобы он был виден при сборке и линковке. Или делать это через интерфейс? Но где объявить его?

Класс можно взять простейший, для примера:

```
 ref class XY
 {
    property Int32 y;
    property Int32 x;
 }
```

В `C/C++` есть для этого инклуд и `typedef`, но тут то как?

Comment: Метка C# здесь точно нужна?

Comment: Вообще то речь о clr Net, аппликация написана на c#, так что мне кажется что вполне уместна.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поместите класс в отдельную DLL на C++/CLI, и пометьте его модификатором public:

```
public ref class XY
```

После этого просто добавьте ссылку на эту DLL во всех проектах, где вам нужен этот класс, и вы сможете его использовать. Заголовочные файлы в .NET не используются, так как вся необходимая информация о типах есть в метаданных сборки.

Казалось бы, все просто. Но есть одна проблема - сборки на C++/CLI (mixed mode) не могут быть AnyCPU, а на C# - могут. Соответственно, если вы делаете, допустим, 32-битную сборку на C++/CLI, добавляете ссылку на нее в AnyCPU проекте, он скомпилируется, но, когда дойдет до загрузки этой сборки в 64-разрядный процесс, все упадет. Решить эту проблему можно созданием отдельной сборки под каждую процессорную архитектуру и ручной загрузкой нужной во время выполнения в обработчике события [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve?view=netframework-4.7).

Comment: Да, про кросс линкинг понятно, но этот способ серьезно плодит сущности и перелинковку между собой. Спасибо за развернутый ответ, особенно про битность. Вероятно это самое короткое и быстрое по реализации решение.